# Php mysql to update only empty column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Consider I have 4 columns in a table and i have datas for 3 columns like below

```
TableTest

Col1  | Col2  | Col3
D11   | D12   |   
D21   | D22   |
```

Normally the update query would be

```
Update TableTest SET Col1 = D11 , Col2 = D12 , COL3 = newdata Where Col1= D11
```

The Scenario is , the update query should only push data to the COL3 , it should skip the Col1 and Col2, as it has already filled with data(even if same or different data for the Col1 and Col2)

Comment: provide sample example

Comment: If you just want to update Col3 you can just leave off the other cols, e.g. Update TableTest SET Col3 = newdata Where Col1= D11

Comment: you can use `.... SET Col2 = CASE WHEN Col2 = '' THEN 'newdata' ELSE Col2 END, .....`. this assumes meaning of empty is `''` if null is empty or also expected you may need to modify the `WHEN` accordingly

Comment: " 56 rows and also also with thousands of records " So, does it have 56 or thousands?

Comment: 56 columns , it was my typing mistake

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might help -

```
UPDATE TableTest a
INNER JOIN TableTest b ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
SET a.Col3 = 'newData'
WHERE a.Col3 IS NULL
```

An `INNER JOIN` with the same table so that it updates the appropriate row!

Comment: i only know the one way that i have share in my answer this is good.

Comment: UPDATE fetcheddata a
INNER JOIN fetcheddata b ON a.`OD_Order_ID_V` = b.`OD_Order_ID_V`
SET a.`OD_Online_Listing_ID_V` = 12
WHERE a.`OD_Online_Listing_ID_V` IS NULL and a.OD_Order_ID_V='CS44189505';         
it doesnot helped me well

Comment: Check if it is `NULL` or blank value.

Comment: UPDATE fetcheddata a
INNER JOIN fetcheddata b ON a.`OD_Order_ID_V` = b.`OD_Order_ID_V`
SET a.`EM_Date_D` = '2015-12-20'
WHERE (a.`EM_Date_D` IS NULL or a.`EM_Date_D`='') and a.OD_Order_ID_V='CS44189505'; dude working great , i owe to thankfull to you.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to update COL3 than don't include other columns in UPDATE query.

**Query:**

```
Update TableTest SET COL3 = newdata Where Col1= D11
```

Answer (score 4):

You should **update whole table using single query** as:

```
Update TableSet SET COL3=CONCAT('D',CONVERT(Substr(Col2,2),INT)+1)
```

This will update table as follows:

```
TableTest

Col1  | Col2  | Col3
D11   | D12   |  D13 
D21   | D22   |  D23
```

Comment: Can u explain what it will do ?

Answer (score 3):

Just do it, like this:

```
Update TableTest SET  COL3 = newdata Where Col1= D11
```

Comment: It's too short without a minimum of explanation. Please, add more comments on your answer to make it a complete one.

Answer (score 2):

In **UPDATE** query, there is no need to reassign the value of **col1** and **col2** if those values are not changing.

```
UPDATE TableTest 
SET COL3 = newdata 
WHERE Col1= 'D11';
```